# How to change drop down variable in select check box button in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to change drop down variables in a select checkbox button in woo commerce.

On product page I would like to to show check box variables instead of drop down variables:

```
<table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $options ) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="label"><label for="<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ); ?>">
                    <?php echo wc_attribute_label( $attribute_name ); // WPCS: XSS ok. ?></label></td>
            <td class="value">
                <?php
                        wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options( array(
                            'options'   => $options,
                            'attribute' => $attribute_name,
                            'product'   => $product,
                        ) );
                        echo end( $attribute_keys ) === $attribute_name ? wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_reset_variations_link', '<a class="reset_variations" href="#">' . esc_html__( 'Clear', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>' ) ) : '';
                    ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It's related to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40661032/using-checkboxes-for-variations-in-woocommerce-to-allow-multiple-choice please have a look